# value error in python script

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have imported all the packages correctly

```
import Queue
from collections import deque, Counter 
import os
import pyttsx
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import serial
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import struct
from threading import Thread
import time
import cPickle as pickle
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


pass


class DataSet:
def __init__(self, savePath):
    self.savePath = savePath
    self.data = {}

@staticmethod
def load(filePath):
    with open(filePath, "rb") as f:
        dataSet, dataTuple = pickle.load(f)
        dataSet.data = dict(dataTuple)
        return dataSet

def save(self):
    with open(self.savePath, "wb") as f:
        everything = [self, self.data.items()]
        pickle.dump(everything, f)

def add(self, classType, vector):
    if classType not in self.data:
        self.data[classType] = []
    self.data[classType].append(vector)        

def combine(self, otherDataSet):
    for k, values in otherDataSet.data.items():
        if k not in self.data:
            self.data[k] = []
        self.data[k].extend(values)

def getLabelsAndInstances(self, labels=None):
    """ Returns a list with each of the labes and a list with each
    of the instance groups in an array format.
    """
    if labels is None:
        labels = sorted(self.data.keys())
    instances = [np.array(self.data[l]) for l in labels]
    return labels, instances

def getLabelsAndInstances2(self, specificLabels=None):
    """ Returns two arrays. One contains the labels and the other 
    contains all of the instances, whose labels can be found in the
    initial array.
    """
    # Format into two continious lists/arrays
    labels, instancesGrouppList = self.getLabelsAndInstances(specificLabels)

    labels2 = []
    instancesGrouppList2 = []
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        instT = instancesGrouppList[i]
        instancesGrouppList2.append(instT)       
        labels2.append([labels[i]]*instT.shape[0])

    return np.hstack(labels2), np.vstack(instancesGrouppList2)    

class SerialWrapper(Thread):
 HEADER = struct.pack("BBBB", 0xA1, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xD4)
 FORMAT = "BBBB" + "hhhhhh" + "HHHHH" + "BB" + "H"

 def __init__(self, port):
    super(SerialWrapper, self).__init__()
    self.ser = serial.Serial(port)
    self.ser.flushInput()
#         self.ser.read(self.ser.inWaiting())
    self.packer = struct.Struct(self.FORMAT)
    self.packetLen = self.packer.size
    self.queue = Queue.Queue()
    self.running = False

    self.freq = {"freq":0, "lastT":time.time()}

 def getPacket(self):
    if self.queue.empty():
        return None
    else:
        return self.queue.get()

 def run(self):
    self.running = True

    headerSize = len(self.HEADER)

    unprocessedData = ""
    while self.running:
        try:
            unprocessedData += self.ser.read(1)
            unprocessedData += self.ser.read(self.ser.inWaiting())
        except:
            print "Serial was closed?"
            break

        # Extract all packets
        while True:
            hLoc = unprocessedData.find(self.HEADER)
            if hLoc == -1:
                break

            unprocessedData = unprocessedData[hLoc:]
            if len(unprocessedData) < self.packetLen:
                break

            packetStr = unprocessedData[:self.packetLen]
            unprocessedData = unprocessedData[self.packetLen:]

            if packetStr[1:].find(self.HEADER) != -1:
                continue

            packetT = self.packer.unpack(packetStr)[headerSize:]

            # Checksum
            receivedSum = packetT[-1]
            calculatedSum = 0
            for i in range(4, len(packetStr)-2):
                calculatedSum += ord(packetStr[i])
            if receivedSum == calculatedSum:
                self.queue.put(packetT[:-1])

#                 print "Checksum..."
#                 print packetStr.encode("hex")
#                 print unprocessedData.encode("hex")
#                 print packetT
#                 print receivedSum, calculatedSum      

            # Frequency check
            t = float(time.time())
            self.freq["freq"] = 1/(t-self.freq["lastT"])
            self.freq["lastT"] = t     

def close(self):
    self.running = False
    self.ser.close()
    print "Closed serial port..."

def clear(self):
    self.queue = Queue.Queue()

class DataGather(Thread):

 def __init__(self, port, dataSet, startDelay=0):
    super(DataGather, self).__init__()
    self.glove = SerialWrapper(port)
    self.dataSet = dataSet
    self.signToGather = ""
    self.startDelay = startDelay
    self.running = False

 def setSignToGather(self, sign):
    self.signToGather = sign

 def run(self):
    time.sleep(self.startDelay)

    self.running = True
    self.glove.start()
    while self.running:
        packet = self.glove.getPacket()
        if packet is not None:
            self.dataSet.add(self.signToGather, packet)
            print "Num of instances: ",len(self.dataSet.data[self.signToGather])
        else:
            time.sleep(.001)

def stop(self):
    self.running = False            
    self.glove.close()

pass

# EXECUTION FUNCTIONS
def gatherNSamples(serialObj, n):
gathered = []
while len(gathered) < n:
    inst = serialObj.getPacket()
    if inst is not None:
        gathered.append(inst)
        print len(gathered)
return gathered

def gatherData(port, dataSet):
 message = "Type 's' to continue and add the new data to the data set"
 message += "\n"
 message += "Type 'd' to trash the new data"
 message += "\n"
 message += "Type 'delete full sign' to erase all data for this sign\n"

 # Request sign
 sign = raw_input("Which sign will you be recording?")    

 tempDataSet = DataSet("temp.pickle")

 dg = DataGather(port, tempDataSet, startDelay=2)
 dg.setSignToGather(sign)
 dg.start()

#     # Print frequency
#     fThread = Thread(target=_printFreq, args=(dg.glove,))
#     fThread.isDaemon() 
#     fThread.start()

raw_input("Hit Enter to stop...")
dg.stop()
decided = False
while not decided:
    result = raw_input(message)
    if result == "d":
        decided = True
    elif result == "s":
        dataSet.combine(tempDataSet)
        decided = True
    elif result == "delete full sign":
        print "Deleted {} instances".format(len(dataSet.data[sign]))
        dataSet.data[sign] = []
        decided = True            
    else:
        print "\nUnkown command...\n"

if sign in dataSet.data:
    print "Total data for this sign: ", len(dataSet.data[sign])
else:
    print "Sign was not stored in data set"
dataSet.save() 

def gatherAlphabet(port, dataSet):

totalPerLetter = 500
totalPerIteration = 100

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabet = [l for l in alphabet] + ["nothing", "relaxed"] 

message = "Enter to accept and gather \n"
message += "Type 'quit' to discard data \n\n"

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

tempDataSet = DataSet("temp.pickle")
glove = SerialWrapper(port)
glove.start()

# Start gathering data
gatheredPerLetter = 0
while gatheredPerLetter < totalPerLetter:
    np.random.shuffle(alphabet)
    for l in alphabet:

        # User input
        while True:
            messageT = message + "Recording {} samples of '{}'\n".format(
                                                    totalPerIteration, l)
            result = raw_input(messageT)
            if result == "":
                # Record data
                glove.clear()
                instances = gatherNSamples(glove, totalPerIteration)

                if raw_input("Type 'd' to discard\n") == 'd':
                    continue
                else:
                    [tempDataSet.add(l, inst) for inst in instances]
                    break                                    
            elif result == "quit":
                # Destroy data
                return
            else:
                print "Unkown input...\n"

    gatheredPerLetter += totalPerIteration

 # Decide to store
 message = ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n"
 message += "Type 'save' or 'discard' \n"
 message += ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n"
 while True:
    result = raw_input(message)
    if result == "save":
        dataSet.combine(tempDataSet)
        dataSet.save()
        return
    elif result == "discard":
        return
    else:
        print "Unkown command"

 def simpleTrainAndTest(dataSet):
 percentTest = .2

 # Format into two continious lists/arrays
 labels, instances = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()

 labels2 = []
 instances2 = []
 for i in range(len(labels)):
    instT = instances[i]
#         instT = windowData(instances[i], 10)
    instances2.append(instT)       
    labels2.extend([labels[i]]*instT.shape[0])
 instances2 = np.vstack(instances)  
 instances2 = np.vstack(instances2)  

 scaledInstances = normalizeData(instances2)

 # Separate training from test
 labelsTrain, labelsTest, instanceTrain, instanceTest = train_test_split(
        labels2, scaledInstances, test_size=percentTest)

 # Train and test
 clf = SVC()
 clf.fit(instanceTrain, labelsTrain)

 result = clf.score(instanceTest, labelsTest)

 print "Test and train results was:"
 print result

 def trainSVM(instanceAndLabels=None, dataSet=None, windowSize=10):
 """ Put in either instanceAndLabels or a dataSet 
"""
if dataSet is not None:
    # Format into two continious lists/arrays
    labels, instanceGroupsList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()

    labels2 = []
    instancesGroupsList2 = []
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        instGroupT = windowData(instanceGroupsList[i], windowSize)
        instancesGroupsList2.append(instGroupT)       
        labels2.extend([labels[i]]*instGroupT.shape[0])

    labels = labels2
    instances = np.vstack(instancesGroupsList2) 
   elif instanceAndLabels is not None:
    instances, labels = instanceAndLabels

 # Normalizer
 scaler = StandardScaler()
 scaler.fit(instances)

 # Train
 clf = SVC()
 scaledInstances = scaler.transform(instances)
 clf.fit(scaledInstances, labels)

 return clf, scaler

def testSVM(clf, dataSet):
labels, instances = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()
predictionsLoL = map(clf.predict, instances)

numWrong = 0
numPred = 0
for i in range(len(labels)):
    l = labels[i]
    predList = predictionsLoL[i]
    wrongList = it.ifilter(lambda x: x!=l, predList)

    numWrong += len(wrongList)
    numPred += len(predList)

print "Wrong: ", numWrong
print "Predicted: ", numPred
print "Percent: ", float(numWrong)/numPred

def gestureToSpeech(port, dataSet):
buffSize = 10
countThresh = 9

speechEngine = pyttsx.init()
clf, scaler = trainSVM(dataSet=dataSet, windowSize=1)

glove = SerialWrapper(port)
glove.start()

pBuffer = deque(maxlen=buffSize)
prevOutput = None
while True:
    # Read and predict
    packet = glove.getPacket()
    if packet is None:
        time.sleep(.001)
        continue
    else:
        instance = scaler.transform(np.array(packet))
        [prediction] = clf.predict(instance)
        pBuffer.append(prediction)

 #             print packet, prediction

    # Filter output and debounce
    [(mostCommon, count)] = Counter(pBuffer).most_common(1)

 #         print mostCommon, count

    if count > countThresh:
        if mostCommon != prevOutput:
 #                 print "======"
 #                 print mostCommon
            prevOutput = mostCommon

            if mostCommon == "relaxed":
                print " "
            elif mostCommon != "nothing":
                print mostCommon

            # Speech
            if mostCommon != "nothing" and mostCommon != "relaxed":
                speechEngine.say(mostCommon)
                speechEngine.runAndWait()

pass
# GRAPH FUNCTIONS
def plotClasses(dataSet):
labels, instanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()
instanceGroupListW = [windowData(instanceArray, 10)
                      for instanceArray in instanceGroupList]

 allInstances = np.vstack(instanceGroupList)
#     allInstances = np.vstack(instanceGroupListW)
 scaledInstances = normalizeData(allInstances)

print labels

imageplot = plt.imshow(scaledInstances.T, aspect="auto")

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

def plotSensor(dataSet):

_, instanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()
allInstances = np.vstack(instanceGroupList)

for i in range(allInstances.shape[1]):
    print "Sensor ", i
    sensor = allInstances[:,i]
    plt.plot(range(sensor.size), sensor)
    plt.show()

pass
# TEST FUNCTIONS
def windowData(instanceArray, windowSize):
window = np.ones((windowSize, 1))
windowed = convolve2d(instanceArray, window, mode="valid")
return windowed[::windowSize,:]

def normalizeData(instanceArray):   
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(instanceArray)
return scaler.transform(instanceArray)

def test(port):
s = serial.Serial(port)
print s.read(30).encode('hex')

def test2(port):
serWrap = SerialWrapper(port)
serWrap.start()
print "aaaaa"
time.sleep(50)
serWrap.close()

def _printFreq(serialWObj):
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Freq: {}".format(serialWObj.freq["freq"])

pass
# REPORT FUNCTIONS

def signGroups(dataSet, saveFolder=None):
 _, allInstanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()
allInstances = np.vstack(allInstanceGroupList)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(allInstances)

# A, B, C, D
_, instanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
scaledInstances = scaler.transform(np.vstack(instanceGroupList))

plt.imshow(scaledInstances.T, aspect="auto")
plt.title("Sensor Readings for A, B, C, and D")
plt.xlabel("Instances")
plt.ylabel("Sensors")
plt.colorbar()
if saveFolder is not None:
    plt.savefig(saveFolder+"/abcd.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()

# K, P
_, instanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances(["k", "p"])
scaledInstances = scaler.transform(np.vstack(instanceGroupList))

plt.imshow(scaledInstances.T, aspect="auto")
plt.title("Sensor Readings for K and P")
plt.xlabel("Instances")
plt.ylabel("Sensors")
plt.colorbar()
if saveFolder is not None:
    plt.savefig(saveFolder+"/kp.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()

# I, J, Nothing
_, instanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances(["i", "j", "nothing"])
scaledInstances = scaler.transform(np.vstack(instanceGroupList))

plt.imshow(scaledInstances.T, aspect="auto")
plt.title("Sensor Readings for I, J, and Nothing")
plt.xlabel("Instances")
plt.ylabel("Sensors")
plt.colorbar()
if saveFolder is not None:
    plt.savefig(saveFolder+"/ijnothing.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()

def individualSensors(dataSet, saveFolder=None):
names = ["X-Accel", "Y-Accel", "Z-Accel", 
         "X-Gyro", "Y-Gyro", "Z-Gyro", 
         "Thumb", "Index", "Middle", "Ring", "Index",
         "Side", "Top"]

_, instanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()
allInstances = np.vstack(instanceGroupList)

for i in range(allInstances.shape[1]):
    sensor = allInstances[:,i]
    plt.plot(range(sensor.size), sensor)
    plt.title("Sensor Readings for " + names[i])
    plt.xlabel("Instances")
    plt.ylabel("Sensor Readings")
    if saveFolder is not None:
            plt.savefig(saveFolder+"/{}.png".format(names[i]),bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.show()

def accuracyOverTime(dataSet, saveFolder=None):
instanceCountList = [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 400]
testOn = 100
testsPer = 10

labels, instanceGroupList = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances() 
numInstancesPer = instanceGroupList[0].shape[0]

results = []
for count in instanceCountList:

    # Multiple times to use average
    scoreList = []
    for i in range(testsPer):
        print "Debug: ", (count, i)

        # Get training set and testing set
        indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(numInstancesPer), 
                                   size=testOn+count, replace=False)
        testIndices = np.sort(indices[:testOn])
        trainIndices = np.sort(indices[testOn:])

        testLabelGroupList = [[l]*testOn for l in labels]
        trainLabelGroupList = [[l]*count for l in labels]
        testInstanceGroupList = [instanceG[testIndices] 
                                 for instanceG in instanceGroupList]
        trainInstanceGroupList = [instanceG[trainIndices] 
                                 for instanceG in instanceGroupList]

        testLabels = np.hstack(testLabelGroupList)
        trainLabels = np.hstack(trainLabelGroupList)
        testInstances = np.vstack(testInstanceGroupList)
        trainInstances = np.vstack(trainInstanceGroupList) 

        # Train and predict
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        clf = SVC()

        scaler.fit(np.vstack((testInstances, trainInstances)))
        scaledTestInstances = scaler.transform(testInstances)
        scaledTrainInstances = scaler.transform(trainInstances)

        clf.fit(scaledTrainInstances, trainLabels)
        scoreList.append(clf.score(scaledTestInstances, testLabels))

    results.append(scoreList)

# Average and plot results
averages = np.average(np.array(results), axis=1)
plt.plot(instanceCountList, averages)
plt.title("Accuracy of Variable Size Datasets")
plt.ylabel("Mean accuracy for all labels")
plt.xlabel("Instances per label")
if saveFolder is not None:
    plt.savefig(saveFolder+"/accuracy.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()

def confusionMatrix(dataSet, saveFolder=None):
testPercent = .2
labels, instances = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances2()
scaledInstances = normalizeData(instances)

# Separate training from test
yTrain, yTest, xTrain, xTest = train_test_split(
        labels, scaledInstances, test_size=testPercent)

# Train and predict
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
yPred = clf.predict(xTest)
cm = confusion_matrix(yTest, yPred)

labels, _ = dataSet.getLabelsAndInstances()

plt.matshow(cm, aspect="auto")
plt.ylabel("True label")
plt.xlabel("Predicted label")
plt.yticks(range(28), labels)
plt.xticks(range(28), labels, rotation=90)
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(True)
if saveFolder is not None:
    plt.savefig(saveFolder+"/confussion.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()

def voltageDividerPlots(saveFolder):
vcc = 5
resitances = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
flexValues = np.linspace(11, 27, 10)
for r in resitances:
    voltages = map(lambda x: float(x)/(x + r)*vcc, flexValues)
    plt.plot(flexValues, voltages)

labels = ["Resistance: {}".format(r) for r in resitances]
plt.ylim((0,5))
plt.legend(labels, loc=4)
plt.title("Flex Sensor Output Ranges")
plt.xlabel("Flex Sensor Resistance")
plt.ylabel("Virtual Ground Output")
if saveFolder is not None:
    plt.savefig(saveFolder+"/resitances.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()

def getAllReportPlots(dataSet, saveFolder=None):
signGroups(dataSet, saveFolder)
individualSensors(dataSet, saveFolder)
accuracyOverTime(dataSet, saveFolder)
confusionMatrix(dataSet, saveFolder)
voltageDividerPlots(saveFolder)

pass
# MAIN
# Tests
# test()
# test2("/dev/ttyUSB0")
# while True: pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
print "Starting..."
```

Is the following port declaration correct?

```
port = "COM1"
#     dataSetPath = "alphabet.pickle"
#     dataSetPath = "alphabet_mon.pickle"
dataSetPath = "alphabet_rob.pickle"
#     dataSetPath = "small_set.pickle"
#     dataSetPath = "test.pickle"

# Make or load data set
if os.path.exists(dataSetPath):
    print "Load data set"
    dataSet = DataSet.load(dataSetPath)
else:
    print "New data set"
    dataSet = DataSet(dataSetPath)
    dataSet.save()

# ---------------------------------

# Gather data
#     gatherData(port, dataSet)
#     gatherAlphabet(port, dataSet)

# ---------------------------------

# Print data set
print "\nData Set Size:"
for label, instanceList in sorted(dataSet.data.items()):
    print label, len(instanceList)

# Plotting
#     plotClasses(dataSet)
#     plotSensor(dataSet)
```

how do i import a dataset here?

```
getAllReportPlots(dataSet, "/Python27/site-packages/sklearn/dataset")

# ---------------------------------

# Learning
#     simpleTrainAndTest(dataSet)

#     clf = trainSVM(dataSet)
#     testSVM(clf)

# ---------------------------------

# Continious Prediction
#     gestureToSpeech(port, dataSet)

# ---------------------------------

print "Done"
```

Error:

```
C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts>python machine.py
Starting...
Load data set

Data Set Size:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "machine.py", line 729, in <module>
getAllReportPlots(dataSet, "/Python27/site-packages/sklearn/dataset")
File "machine.py", line 678, in getAllReportPlots
signGroups(dataSet, saveFolder)
File "machine.py", line 512, in signGroups
allInstances = np.vstack(allInstanceGroupList)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 230, in     vstack
return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

If anyone can explain why am i getting this error and the solution?

Comment: Please! For the love of all that is holy and unholy, read and apply this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think anyone has time and patience to read through all these lines of code. Please narrow down your problem, and come up with something compact and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error with:

```
In [230]: np.concatenate([],0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-2a097486ce12> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate([],0)

ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate

In [231]: np.concatenate([np.atleast_2d(i) for i in ()],0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-231-007f2dd2af1b> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate([np.atleast_2d(i) for i in ()],0)

ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

So you need to figure out is why `tup` in the last call is empty.  Or tracing back a step, why `allInstanceGroupList`, the argument to `vstack`  is empty.